# How to open Info Window when clicking a row of an Ajax sortable table

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, dom-events

I have asked something similar but not the same at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10827931/opening-info-window-when-clicking-a-table-row) (and it's already answered). Now I have some follow up question and I think it's better to ask anew (I've read the rules and I hope I don't break any. But if I do please kindly remind me).

I'm loading several cities' id, name, and positions from a MySQL table and then populate it into an HTML table. There's also a Google Maps with markers pointing to those cities.

I want an info window to pop up on the city marker when user click one of the HTML row (tr tag). I'm using PHP, Javascript, and XML without any jQuery. I have achieved this far.

Now I'm trying to make the HTML table to be sortable. So when user clicked the th, the data will be sorted according to the th being clicked (for this sample however, it's only sortable by ID).

The problem is after it's sorted at least once, the Info Window won't pop up anymore when the tr is clicked.

My HTML:

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT id, name, lat, lng FROM city ORDER BY id";
   $arrCities = mysql_query ($query);
?>

<div id="gmap" style="width: 550px; height: 450px"></div>

<table id="tblData">
   <tr>
       <th>/* when the th clicked it'll call js function */
             <a href="javascript:GetData('sort.php?by=id&val=<? echo $val; ?>', 'tblData');">ID</a>
       </th>
       <th>City</th>
   </tr>

   <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($arrCities)) { ?>

       <tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

           <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>

       </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
```

My PHP for creating an XML to populate the markers (my-xml-generator.php):

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT id, name, lat, lng FROM city ORDER BY id";
    $arrCities = mysql_query ($query);

    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8');
    $node = $dom->createElement ('markers');
    $parNode = $dom->appendChild ($node);

    header('Content-type: text/xml');

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($arrCities))
    {
            $node = $dom->createElement ('marker');
            $newNode = $parNode->appendChild ($node);
            $newNode->setAttribute ('id', $row['id']);
            $newNode->setAttribute ('name', $row['name']);
            $newNode->setAttribute ('lat', $row['lat']);
            $newNode->setAttribute ('lng', $row['lng']);
    }

    echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

My Google Maps Javascript:

```
    var gmap = new google.maps.Map (mapDiv, options);

    var arrMarkers = []; 
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    // add markers to the map
    DownloadUrl ("my-xml-generator.php", function(data)
    {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName ("marker");

        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++)
        {
            var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");

            var lat = parseFloat (markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
            var lng = parseFloat (markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
            var pos = new google.maps.LatLng (lat, lng);


            var markerOptions =
            {
                position    : pos,
                map         : gmap,
                draggable   : false
            };

            // add the marker
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker (markerOptions);
            arrMarkers.push(marker);

            // assign onclick event for each tr
            // this is the part that I have to somehow re-run after the sorting is done
            var tr = document.getElementById(id);
            google.maps.event.addDomListener (tr, "click",
                (function(i) {
                    var row = i;
                    return function() {
                        RowClick (row);
                    }
                })(i)
            );


            // add info window
            var html = '<div>' + id + '</div>';

            BindInfoWindow (marker, gmap, infoWindow, html);
        }
    });


    function BindInfoWindow (marker, map, infoWindow, html)
    {
        google.maps.event.addListener (marker, "click", function()
        {
            infoWindow.setContent (html);
            infoWindow.open (map, marker);
        });
    }


    function RowClick (i)
    {
        google.maps.event.trigger (arrMarkers[i], "click");
    }


    function DownloadUrl (url, callback)
    {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
        {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4)
            {
                xhr.onreadystatechange = DoNothing;
                callback(xhr, xhr.status);
            }
        };

        xhr.open ('GET', url, true);
        xhr.send (null);
    }

    function DoNothing() {}
```

My GetData() function (simple and usual one):

```
function GetData (dataSource, divID)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open ("GET", dataSource);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4)
        {               
                var targetDiv = document.getElementById (divID);
                targetDiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
    }

    xhr.send (null);
}
```

My sort.php (my way of sorting is by running a query again to retrieve the desired sorted results and output the tr rows to the table's innerHTML):

```
<?php
   $by = $_GET['by'];
   $val = $_GET['val'];

   $query = "SELECT id, name, lat, lng FROM city ORDER BY $by $val";
   $arrCities = mysql_query ($query);

   // set the new order value
   $val == 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
?>

   <tr>
       <th>
             <a href="javascript:GetData('sort.php?by=id&val=<? echo $val; ?>', 'tblData');">ID</a>
       </th>
       <th>City</th>
   </tr>

   <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($arrCities)) { ?>

       <tr id="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">

           <td><?php echo $row['id']; ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>

       </tr>
   <?php } ?>
</table>
```

When a tr is clicked, the Info Window of the city contained in that tr will pop up correctly. And the sorting also works

But after it was being sorted once than the click events of the tr are obviously gone. How can I reassign it again after it was sorted?

Comment: Honestly dude, no one will read through all of this. Go back and simplify your question to get real help.

Comment: @norse Thanks. I've tried to simplify it as much as I could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Store the ID of the markers.
2. Encapsulate the JS in charge of binding the markers to the rows.
3. Call the encapsulated JS inside the `DownloadUrl` callback and the `GetData` function.

## Store ID

Make arrMarkers an object: `var arrMarkers = {};`

## Encapsulate Bindings

```
function BindMarkerRows() {

    for(var id in arrMarkers) {
        var tr = document.getElementById(id);

        google.maps.event.addDomListener (tr, "click",
            (function(marker) {
                return function() {
                    google.maps.event.trigger (marker, "click");
                }
            })(arrMarkers[id])
        );
    }
}
```

## Update DownloadUrl

```
DownloadUrl ("my-xml-generator.php", function(data) {

    var xml = data.responseXML;
    var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName ("marker");

    for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {

        var id = markers[i].getAttribute("id");

        var lat = parseFloat (markers[i].getAttribute("lat"));
        var lng = parseFloat (markers[i].getAttribute("lng"));
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng (lat, lng);


        var markerOptions =
        {
            position    : pos,
            map         : gmap,
            draggable   : false
        };

        // add the marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker (markerOptions);
        arrMarkers[id] = marker; //Here we access the object as an associative array
    }

    BindMarkerRows();
}
```

## Update GetData

```
function GetData (dataSource, divID)
{
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open ("GET", dataSource);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4)
        {
            var status = xhr.status;

            if ((status >= 200 && status < 300) || status === 304)
            {
                var targetDiv = document.getElementById (divID);
                targetDiv.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                BindMarkerRows();
            }
        }
    }

    xhr.send (null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nick. I don't quite understand it though. You said make arrMarkers as an object, yet in the DownloadUrl you still address it as an array? And btw, can you remove the else part in the GetData function since it's using my local language? So other people won't be confused

Comment: Aaah, I just read your comment in the DownloadUrl. I get it. I'll need some time to try and digest this though. Thank you so much, I'll post an update of the result

Comment: Before sorted, the Info Window will pop up. So your BindMarkerRows() works. But after sorted, the Info Window still won't pop up. I store the GetData() and the BindMarkerRows() in separate .js files. Could it be because of that?

Comment: That's strange. Maybe you could add some dummy code to the BindMarkerRows event handler. That would rule out the event handler from being the source of the problem. In addition to `google.maps.event.trigger (marker, "click");`, add `alert(marker);`.

Comment: The alert(marker) pops up before sorted, and it doesn't after sorted. What does that mean than? Fyi, any alert called from GetData will never pops up

Comment: It means that GetData is not working correctly. Since the alert worked before, it means that the event handler was successfully binded. Alerts **should** work inside the GetData function.

Comment: Alert does work in GetData. The problem was because I wrap all of my Google Maps initialization scripts in `window.onload = function() {...}` so it can be run onload but it also caused the `BindMarkerRows()` to be unrecognized by `GetData()` (which is in separate .js file). Any thoughts to resolve this?

Comment: I resolved it by removing my `window.onload = function() {...}` and call the map initialization at the html instead, like this `<body onload="InitMap()">`    Anyone who's looking at similar problem just look at Nick's answer. Don't read all of these comments. It'll just confuse you. Thanks again, Nick. You've been of great help